# Old extractor fan hole leaking water into new kitchen

Tags: kitchens, exhaust-fan, hole

We had a new kitchen fitted last year, including a new extractor fan above the gas hob. When the previous extractor was removed it revealed the drilled hole and pipe which although lined up perfectly with the old fan, unfortunately did not line up with the new one so we simply covered it with the new one and didn't bother using a hole to extract the steam and heat, but used the old hole to feed a power supply from the garage.

There have been no problems for a year however in the last few weeks we have had a lot of wind and rain and suddenly we are noticing water dripping down the back of the glass splash back which sits beneath the extractor fan.

I have removed the splash back, and the extractor fan itself, and the old pipe was damp and had water sat in it, I'm assuming when the wind blows in the right direction the fans on the outside wall are opening and water is coming in and flowing down the pipe and into the kitchen.

Baring in mind there is now a power cable running down the redundant pipe to power the light in the new extractor fan, what should I do about this water issue.

I have a can of expanding foam that I was considering although I'm not sure I want to use this with the cable sat there.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution for this would be to close off the external vents for this pipe. If weather conditions allow entry of the elements then trying to plug things up internally does not solve the problem. I would remove the old external vent and provide the proper covering whether that be flashing, siding or roofing material.

A very good question is: How are you venting the replacement extractor unit??

Comment: We are using a carbon filter, and do not actually turn on the fans, it is more for aesthetics to finish off the oven suite, rather than function.

Comment: Do you think something like this would do the job, to keep things hassle free http://www.amazon.co.uk/White-Hooded-Bricks-Grilles-Extractors/dp/B00GOVOXHU/ref=sr_1_3?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1448810623&sr=1-3&keywords=air+vent+cover

Comment: I do not want to recommend any particular product. But of the current vent outlet is not utilizing a hooded or shrouded vent cover then installing one would be a good step to keeping the weather conditions out.